# How to output MediaStream to a local mp4 file

Tags: javascript

I see most people ask the other way around. But I am trying to figure out how to do from [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) to a local mp4 file (or maybe a list of format). Did lots of research, but not result.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API
check this instruction